# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'webkitEnterFullScreen'

Tags: jquery, html, fullscreen

I'm trying to use the html5 fullscreen api in a popup window, but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'webkitEnterFullScreen'
```

and here is my html :

```
<html lang="en"><head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Negar - one</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Negar/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Negar/js/viewer.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #main-content{height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in;
               -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in;
                -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-in;
                    transition: transform 1s ease-in;
            }
        </style>
    </head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css,">

    <body>
        <section id="main-content">   some code here   </section>

</body></html>
```

and this is my function :

```
$("#main-content").get(0).webkitEnterFullScreen();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request for entering fullscreen should probably be made from the user. You could try something like this to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
<script>
    function goFs(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);

        if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="test">
    Hi there!
</div>

<button onclick="goFs('test');">Full screen?</button>
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/73Wus/show/

Note: I had to share the full jsFiddle page because `iframe`'s require a special attribute to allow fullscreen, as shown below:

```
<iframe src="127.0.0.1" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

...Usual Fiddle can be found [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/73Wus/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid `webkitEnterFullScreen()` is only applicable for video element.

see the [API manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/HTMLVideoElementClassReference/HTMLVideoElement/HTMLVideoElement.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/HTMLVideoElement/webkitEnterFullscreen)

Try

```
<video id="my-video"></video>
```

and

```
$("#my-video")[0].webkitEnterFullScreen();
```

Comment: This is not true.  See http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/26517/using-the-browsers-new-html5-fullscreen-capabilities/ for an example of full screen with an image.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#main-content")[0].webkitEnterFullScreen();
```

Comment: @hakim-sina there is a link tag outside of the head tag, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css,">` this makes your markup invalid, your jquery file has been loaded?

Comment: ohh I dont know how it got there ! in my original code I don have that, but after serverside processing it appears ! how do I get rid of it ?

Comment: @hakim-sina what kind of server processing makes a link tag?

Comment: I don't know, I'm using php for my serverside, and here is the only part that I've used it here :
        <section id="main-content">
           <?php echo urldecode($row0['html']) ?>
        </section>